# How to convert firebase Timestamp to String Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, timestamp

I'm saving some publications in the FireStoreDataBase and I get the time when the post is created like this:

`Date datahorario = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();`

This info is saved in the database in the timestamp format, like this:

[image]

When I try to return this specific field to display in the APP, I receive the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type com.google.firebase.Timestamp to String (found in field 'datahorario')

This is my java Posts.class:

```
package com.example.miratown;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Posts {

    String descricao, titulo, categoria, fotourl, latitude, longitude, anonimo, pais, estado, cidade, endereco, usuario, datahorario;

    public Posts(){}

    public Posts( String datahorario, String descricao, String titulo, String categoria, String fotourl, String latitude, String longitude, String anonimo, String pais, String estado, String cidade, String endereco, String usuario) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.fotourl = fotourl;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.anonimo = anonimo;

        this.datahorario = datahorario;

        this.pais = pais;
        this.estado = estado;
        this.cidade = cidade;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {

        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }


    public String getCategoria() {

        return categoria;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getAnonimo() {
        return anonimo;
    }

    public String getDatahorario() {return datahorario; }

    public String getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }





    public String getFotourl() {

        return fotourl;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public void setFotourl(String fotourl) {
        this.fotourl = fotourl;
    }


    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setAnonimo(String anonimo) {
        this.anonimo = anonimo;
    }

    public void setDatahorario(String datahorario) { this.datahorario = datahorario; }

    public void setPais(String pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
}
```

How is the correct way to convert the TimeStamp value receveid from FireBase to a String before presenting the value in my TextView?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: You can try using the `Date` object instead of `String` as your function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says:

> Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type com.google.firebase.Timestamp to String (found in field 'datahorario')

So the Firebase SDK is not able to deserialize the `Timestamp` value from the database into the string `datahorario` field that you have in your class.

You should declare the `datahorario` field as either a Java `Date` or a Firestore-specific `Timestamp`.